# Windows 10: how to automatically set all new connections to 'metered'?

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to enable 'metered' by default for all new connections?

I travel a lot, which means I check into new hotels quite a lot, and I have to remember to set every new connection to 'metered' after connecting for the first time (hotel connections being bad enough as it is, and because I don't want to be surprised by updates while on the road). Is there some way to set metered to be on automatically for new connections?

Note:

- I already know how to set it manually; that's not what this question is about.
- I understand the importance of updates, and make sure I update the laptop before leaving my home. However, in the 2-4 weeks after while I'm traveling I do not want it to suddenly decide to spend an hour updating itself, or even worse, accidentally brick itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SuperUser.

Inspired by the accepted answer to [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113852/set-unset-mobile-connections-as-metered), you can accomplish what you desire by editing the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost` section of the registry.

Set `WiFi` to `2`. (`1` is unmetered; `2` is metered.)

## Notes

- The typical permissions on the DefaultMediaCost are such that you probably can't change the values. You'll need to modify the permissions to give yourself write-access. Full details are in the linked answer.
- It is reported that a change to the DefaultMediaSet registry settings requires a reboot to become effective.
- Changing the behavior of Windows via the registry -- especially undocumented portions -- is risky. The implementation details can change without notice.