# Is there a way to restrict Windows on energy and other resources for its auto background processes that are unwanted by the user?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, resource-usage

Is there a way to restrict Windows to not use more than some certain amount of energy and other resources for its auto background processes that are unwanted by the user?

Almost everyday, specially if my laptop is connected to electricity (not on battery mode) suddenly some random auto processes from Windows starts eating energy and making my computer hot and having loud noise of fan etc! Such as telemetry, update, windows infrastructure host, service and controller app ... . For some of them if I right click on them in task manager to end the task, it says doing so will end up shutting down the windows! How can I get rid of these background processes of windows? Or at least restricting them to not over-use resources? Not only the noise, heat and power usage are annoying, but also let's say I am running a code that I wrote and I want to measure the time, memory and cpu usage of it, sometimes having some unwanted processes being run on background can effect on the numbers I get in my measurement and it is annoying to rely on luck that when Windows is not wasting my resources! Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Windows information: Windows 10 Enterprise, version 21H2.

Comment: See what you are running (Admin Tools, Resource Monitor).  I have SSD computers here (Windows 10 then 11) and average consumption when connected to AC is about 11 watts.

Answer (score 1):

There are *Registry* settings to limit CPU and disk I/O for tasks such as [Windows *Defender*](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-security/limit-windows-defender-cpu-usage/m-p/1511280) periodic scans and [*Search* indexing](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/searchindexer-exe-high-cpu-usage), but I and others have found those settings largely ignored.

You can turn off telemetry, updates and other processes through the [Windows Settings CPL](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/12/configure-telemetry-windows-10/), [Group Policies](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/12/configure-telemetry-windows-10/), [Registry changes](https://wethegeek.com/how-to-disable-telemetry-and-data-collection-in-windows-10/), and so forth.

However, changing settings one-by-one, unless scripted, is a nuisance. It is easier to use a third-party tool such as free [O&O ShutUp10++](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) or one of the [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/shutup10/) to stop telemetry, and also control other leaks of personal identifying information (PII) and other security and privacy issues.

*Caveat:* Before installing or using new software, check reviews online, and evaluate the file in [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).

[image: Stop telemetry with ShutUp10]

**However,** if you restrict automatic updates, (which can also be turned off by [setting network connections *DefaultMediaCost* metered](https://superuser.com/questions/1113852/set-unset-mobile-connections-as-metered)), or routine tasks, such as *Search* indexing and disk optimization, **be sure that those tasks are run on a regular basis!**